# AngularJS routeChangeStart not working when on homepage

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog

I can capture the Back Button in an AngularJs app using the `$locationChangeStart` event, so I can close a modal.

This works when I navigate away from the first page and then click a modal, then click back, I capture the Back event and close the modal and prevent the browser back default.

The problem is it does not work when on the homepage, none of the events get fired so I can't prevent default and close the modal, it just goes back to the new tab page (google)

```
$rootScope.$on("$locationChangeStart", function (event, next, current) {
   event.preventDefault();
   console.log('$locationChangeStart 1 ');
});

$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function (scope, next, current) {
   event.preventDefault();
   console.log('$routeChangeStart');
});

$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
   event.preventDefault();
   console.log('$stateChangeStart');
});

$rootScope.$on('$destroy', function (event, next, current) {
   event.preventDefault();
   console.log('$locationChangeStart');
});
```

I'm using `$routeProvider` and don't really want to have to re-write it in ui-router.
Is there some config I have missed to get these events to fire when on my first page? or is there a hack?
thanks